# How could I shorten my mysql query to allow me to swap indexes in my mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$database->query("UPDATE main_navigation SET id = ? WHERE id = ?", array($intTempIndex, $intNewIndex));
$database->query("UPDATE main_navigation SET id = ? WHERE id = ?", array($intNewIndex, $intOldIndex));
$database->query("UPDATE main_navigation SET id = ? WHERE id = ?", array($intOldIndex, $intTempIndex));
```

I'm having a little trouble figuring out a shorter way then using 3 queries to swap id's in my database. Is it possible to shorten more then this? Could I see an example if so.

NOTE: $database->query is my custom function.

Comment: Would you please add the the name of the Database Handler Object your using E.G PDO or inform users your using a custom DB handler Object (i little confusing if some one hits this from google)

Answer (score 0):

```
update main_navigation
set id = case
    when i1 then i2
    when i2 then i1
end
where id in (i1, i2);
```

(edited to add a where clause so as to not update all rows -- meh)

Comment: The 2-query version would be this: swapping 1 and 2 would : `{1 and 2}`  change 1 in 2 `{2 and 2}` change 2 in 1 `{1 and 1}` => this doesn't look like a swap to me.

Comment: Well, I just understood why a temporary was needed: there is a unique constraint on `id`...

Comment: With a unique constraint you would get a problem with your version AND with the 2-query version you seemed to imply. Without the unique constraint you will get what I posted: 2 the same values, because you can't distinguish between the swapped an the to-be-swapped one.

Comment: @Nanne NO you wouldn't! That is the whole point of that statement: it is atomic! Try it

Comment: anyway, my first comment was regarding your statement about 2-way